# Prevent microtype tracking to add space between letters?

Tags: spacing, microtype

I use a latex template with small caps for chapter titles. These are spaced a bit using \textls from microtype package. Unfortunately, microtype does not properly increase the tracking but rather add spaces between letters which makes the text unsearchable :(

Do you know of any clean way to set the font tracking? I sounds like it is what microtype is supposed to do…

> from
> https://texfaq.org/FAQ-letterspace
>
> Possibly the ‘ultimate’ in this field
> is the microtype, which uses the
> micro-typography capabilities of
> current PDFTeX to provide a \textls
> command, which operates according to
> parameters declared in a \SetTracking
> command. Microtype’s ‘tracking’
> facility expands the natural spacing
> font itself, rather than inserting
> space between characters. Ordinarily,
> letter-spacing will destroy ligatures;
> however, this is wrong if the font is
> of a fraktur style, and the package
> provides a means of protecting the
> ligatures in a letter-spaced text.

But it definitely does not with my latex install

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009)
>
> Package: microtype 2009/03/27 v2.3d Micro-typography with pdfTeX (RS)

You may wonder why I am not using Tex Live 2010… I am not so keen reinstalling all the minionpro package… but if it really helps I'll do it.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx. You don't need to add your name to questions, since it appears bottom right anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, after searching trying to oopen the pdf in adobe illustrator, I realized that microtype does a good job: the problem came from my pdf reader Skim.

Hope this entry may help a few other puzzled skim users ;)